# ARIMA(0,2,2) model - equation derivation

Tags: time-series, arima

So on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average#Examples) under *Examples*, it is mentioned that *ARIMA(0,2,2)* is given by:

$$
X_t = 2X_{t-1} - X_{t-2} + (\alpha + \beta -2)\epsilon_{t-1} + (1 - \alpha)\epsilon_{t-2} + \epsilon_t \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

**My question is:** how this equation has been derived?

We know that *ARIMA(0,2,2)* means $d=2$ (second order differencing) and $q=2$ is the MA (moving-average) order.

If $MA(q)$ is [given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model):
$$
X_t = \mu + \epsilon_t + \theta_1\epsilon_{t-1} + ... + \theta_q\epsilon_{t-q}
$$

therefore (?):

$$
X_t = \mu + \epsilon_t + \theta_1\epsilon_{t-1} + \theta_2\epsilon_{t-2} \\
X_{t-1} = \mu + \epsilon_{t-1} + \theta_1\epsilon_{t-2} + \theta_2\epsilon_{t-3}
\\
X_{t-2} = \mu + \epsilon_{t-2} + \theta_1\epsilon_{t-3} + \theta_2\epsilon_{t-4}
$$

After removing $\epsilon_{t-3}, \epsilon_{t-3}$, for the second order differencing we compute $X_t - 2X_{t-1} + X_{t-2}$:

$$
X_t - 2X_{t-1} + X_{t-2} = (\theta_1 - 2)\epsilon_{t-1} + (\theta_2 - 2\theta_1 + 1)\epsilon_{t-2} + \epsilon_t
$$

and the coefficients of the error terms differ from those in *(1)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I realised that we just need to substitute:
$$
\alpha = 2\theta_1 - \theta_2 \\
\beta = -\theta_1 + \theta_2
$$
although I do not quite understand what was the reasoning behind this particular substitution.

Comment: [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385918/how-do-i-prove-that-arima0-1-1-is-equivalent-to-simple-exponential-smoothing/385931#385931) is my answer for a similar question

Comment: @Tomasz Bartkowiak: it is a weird notation but it comes from the fact that the arima(0,2,2) is equivalent to a local level model which is a structural time series model. If you look that up, you'll probably see why they wrote it in that strange way initially. They should have explained why. You can look at Andrew Harvey's blue covered text ( I forget the title )  for what the local level model is. Also, if you're not interested in structural time series, don't worry about it and don't let it confuse you. Definitely a confusing move by the author of original equation.