Best parameter of exponential smoothing when applied on a random walk
Let's say I have a random walk:
$$X_t = X_0 + \sum_{i =1}^t \epsilon_i$$
with the $\epsilon_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ and independent.
Then what smoothing factor $\alpha$ in an exponential moving average of windows $N$ gives the best estimate of $X_{T+1}$?
I feel like it should depend on $\sigma$. Like if $\sigma$ is large I would intuitively weight less the most recent values, and if $\sigma$ is small i would weight more the most recent values.
But is there a closed form for the $\alpha$ that gives the best estimate?

Intuitively--because $\sigma$ merely establishes a unit of measurement for the $X_t$--the answer should not depend on $\sigma$ at all.  If some statistical procedure depended on whether you expressed your data in dollars or thousands of dollars, for instance, then that procedure would be arbitrary and rather suspect.

$X_t = X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$. So $\text{E}(X_t | X_1,\dots,X_{t-1}) = X_{t-1}$. Therefore choosing $\alpha = 1$ is optimal, regardless of the variance of $\epsilon_t$.

Rob is absolutely correct but dddqdxqfq should note  that $\alpha = 1$ is no longer exponential smoothing. ES works for models whose mean is constant and an RW does not have a constant mean. This is why Rob had to go outside ES to find the optimal value of $\alpha$.

@mlofton, if I remember correctly, ES implies presence of a unit root, so I wonder how that squares with what you are saying.

Hi Richard: The link below shows the equivalence. of ES and the ARIMA(0,1,1). Notice that  you are correct to say that, by setting $\alpha = 1$ in the ARIMA(0,1,1), one is really constructing a ARIMA(0,1,0) model ( a unit root model ) because $\theta = 0$. But I would  argue that it's then no longer an ARIMA(0,1,1) model which implies that it's really no longer an ES model either. I hope that this clarifies the issue.

I forgot  the link. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385918/how-do-i-prove-that-arima0-1-1-is-equivalent-to-simple-exponential-smoothing
